# Highlight the text string in HTML CSS with php

Tags: php, html, css, regex

I'm looking for a quick way to highlight a text string if it has a flag i.e.(-R) as a first symbol in it, from the beginning till the line end (\n).

The function will be given a text of a multiple strings separated with "\n" that may or may not contain any flags at all. Something like this:

```
-Rnotes to be red
-Ynotes to be yellow
-G notes to be green
```

In the output of this function I need to get this:

```
<span style="background-color:red">notes to be red</span>
<span style="background-color:yellow">notes to be yellow</span>
<span style="background-color:green"> notes to be green</span>
```

Comment: javascript would be better for this if page is already loaded

Comment: As @clearshot66 mentioned use javascript. You can use a switch statement and use susbtring to get the letter

Comment: Also, if they may or may not begin with a flag, what's preventing a user from inputting -R before their note and potentially messing something up?

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 1):

Based on Matt's answer I made this answer.
Keep in mind it's Matt's idea it's based from so don't forget to upvote his answer if you like this.

I use str_replace to replace `-R` (or Y or G) with the span tag and use the `-R` as the key in color array.
Then I just add closing span tag.

```
$notes = array(
    '-Rnote',
    '-Gnote',
    '-Ynote',
    '-Rnote1',
    '-Gnote1',
    '-Ynote1',
);
// Above array can be replaced by:
// $notes = explode("\n", $text);

$colors = array(
    '-R' => 'red',
    '-G' => 'green',
    '-Y' => 'yellow',
);

foreach ($notes as $note ) {
    If (isset($colors[substr($note,0,2)])){
        echo str_replace(substr($note, 0, 2), '<span style="background-color:' . $colors[substr($note, 0, 2)] . '">', $note) . "</span>\n";
    }Else{
        Echo $note ."\n";
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/9YDAX

Edit noticed how I forgot that there may not be a color tag in the string.
Added a echo of no color notes

Comment: This is the better non-regex approach.  A lookup array is best practice for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something link this:

```
$notes = array(
    '-Rnote',
    '-Gnote',
    '-Ynote',
    '-Rnote1',
    '-Gnote1',
    '-Ynote1',
);

$colors = array(
    'R' => 'red',
    'G' => 'green',
    'Y' => 'yellow',
);

foreach ($notes as $note ) {

    $color_key = substr($note, 1, 1);
    $note_string = substr($note, 2);

    $bg_color = array_key_exists($color_key, $colors) ? $colors[$color_key] : '';
    echo '<p style="background-color:' . $bg_color . '">' . $note_string . '</p>';
}
```

Storing your colors in an associative array may make it easy to add more colors in the future.

This might be a little messy, but it should work for you.

Comment: Good one! But I think it should be like this https://3v4l.org/kTHkX outputting the "note" in the span

Comment: You are probably right. I think I just did that for testing and forgot to set it back.

Comment: Sorry updated the link I accidentally used $note, a variable you already used

Comment: I think you should edit your answer. Or add a second line of "option 2" code. I believe you will get a badge for first edit also.

Comment: Never post an answer that you believe "might be a little bit messy".  Your method will make red text out of `BROTHER`

Comment: yes, I agree. However the condition he gave was the values would "be a flag i.e.(-R)". So the answer still works based on what he asked for.

Comment: @Matt well Mick is correct, the question does say `may or may not contain any flags at all.` but OP did not include any example of flag not being there. For all we know it could mean "two spaces and the note" if there is no flag. Or like Mick assumes. I'd say with the provided information your answer is correct. But if it is "incorrect" it's a minor edit to fix it.